# C# Oledb like statement not returning any results

Tags: c#, oledb, sql-like

I'm making a simple asp.net/c# application and everything with the Oledb worked just fine until now.
The like statement is just not working through c#, it worked as a SQL Query in Access. I also tried just using `'*a*'` instead of `'*@uname*'` but it still didn't return anything.

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(
    "SELECT accounts.ID, uname, firstname, lastname, description FROM accounts, profiles " +
    "WHERE accounts.ID = profiles.ID AND uname like '*@uname*'", connection);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@uname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tbxFilter.Text;
```

Comment: Should it be `'%?%'`? Also, it looks like you wanna do a join

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but why % doesn't work in access and * does?

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked, please mark it as accepted. I think that % should work in access as well after reading the documentation

Comment: Oskar, not only does it appear he wants to do a join, he is. It is simply different syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, from here I can see a fast way to fix it:

```
WHERE accounts.ID = profiles.ID AND uname like @uname
```

and then your parameter should be defined like this:

```
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@uname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + tbxFilter.Text + "%"
```

or

```
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@uname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "*" + tbxFilter.Text + "*".
```

A side note: if I were you, I would not include the tbxFilter.Text directly. Instead, you should use this:

```
tbxFilter.Text.Replace("'", "''")
```

since a ' sign in your parameter will hurt your SQL query if not doubled. Either that or you perform this safety check on your text control's handlers.

Comment: @Vladmir when you use parameters and add, you are safe from sql injection

Comment: You don't need to do `tbxFilter.Replace(...)`.  By using a parameter this escaping is taken care of for you.

Comment: I knew about that, but I do remember (and I might be wrong) that a single ' just ruins your query solely syntactically. Alrighty, I see your point, Sean.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're not using the correct wildcard character. Access can use either `*` or `%`, but most other use only `%`

Comment: @DanielxFx I think you should use: '%?%'. Parameters are put at the question mark

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works for me in my DB.

```
dataAdapter
    .SelectCommand
    .Parameters
    .Add(new OleDbParameter("uname", "?" + tbxFilter.Text + "?"));
```